# Android kill all other activities on starting a new one

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, flags, kill-process

I have an android activity problem.

Here is how my process works:

1. `Login Activity` starts
2. Login successful. `MainMenuActivity` starts and LoginActivity is finished by me.
3. User touched on settings and SettingsActivity starts. `MainMenuActivity` is NOT finished. because is it the main menu. when user presses the back on settings screen I need to go back `MainMenuActivity`. so I cant kill `MainMenu`.
4. User touched on log out and `SettingsActivity` is finished by me and Login activity starts. As user returns the login I need to kill `MainMenuActivity` but I cant.:/
5. I tried `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`, `CLEAR_TOP`, `SINGLE_TASK`, `NEW_TASK`, `NO_HISTORY` etc.. almost all of them didnt work
6. I put `launchMode="singleTask"`, `clearTaskOnLaunh="true"` etc. didtn work again.
7. I tried `addFlags()` and `setFlags()` both, didnt work
8. There are some many issues about this topic here, I read and applied all the suggested solutions and didnt work.

Can anyone help, please?

**P.S** `android:minSdkVersion="8"` and `android:targetSdkVersion="15"` for my app. I didnt use fragments in the app, I use old activity structure.

Comment: please use NO_HISTORY and manually do the backpress by overiding  onBackpress meathod..I think that will solve your problem

Answer (score 6):

Use the combination of two flags like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
```

This deletes all the other activities and starts this one.

Try this.

For api level <11

```
i.addFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | 
              Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
```

Comment: actually it seems there is no flag as Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK maybe you meant this :Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET?

Comment: this is available from API level 11

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098279/alternative-to-intent-flag-activity-clear-task

Comment: OP says `minSdkVersion="8"` in his post. He can't use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`. You need to read the question before you answer it.

Comment: My mistake. But the link I posted gives an alternave to this flag

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest to start the settings activity for result (see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)), and when the user requests to logout, set a result accordingly. You will get this result in MainActivity's onActivityResult (see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29)) and can handle the logout there, finishing the mainActivity before starting the loginActivity.

Comment: your solution seems reasonable, this will work definetely. only more rows then settings a flag, thanks. probably I use this. I appreicate

Comment: this works fine. very thank you. but I hope I can learn how to do it with flags some day.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you don't finish the `Login` activity when you start the main menu. Then you can always clear all activities on logout by doing this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

This will only work if `Login` activity is still active at the root (beginning) of the task stack.

To prevent the user from BACKing into the `Login` activity from the `Main` activity, you can override `onBackPressed()` in `Main` activity and do something else.

Answer (score 0):

Use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP like this-

```
Intent loginIntent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
        loginIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
    finish();
```

Comment: I already tried this, but I also tried one more time after you wrote but it did not work. thanks.

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, StartupActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();

Comment: This doesn't work because the `Login` activity is not in the task stack. He has already finished it. This would work if the `Login` activity were still at the root of the task stack.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyActivity2.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
```

1. in this example Mainactivity automatically closed and Myactivity2 Start.
   and one thing you need to add finish();